# Let $B$ have distribution $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$. Then what is $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathsf P\left[ \frac{B}{n} < p\right]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $B$ have distribution $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$. What is the tool for analysing $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathsf P\left[ \frac{B}{n} < p\right]$$?

I think the answer should be  $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathsf P\left[ \frac{B}{n} < p\right]=\frac{1}{2}$. My reasoning is that $np$ is roughly the median of $B$ hence the limit should be $1/2$. 
However, I would like to see a proper proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have by the [De Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) $$\mathsf P\left(\frac B n < p\right)=\mathsf P\left(\frac{B - n p}{\sqrt n\sqrt{p (1-p)}}<0\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(\mathcal N(0,1)<0) = \frac12.$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you take at  a look at the following generalization of this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625930/let-b-be-binomial-with-n-p-what-is-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-p-b-le

Comment: I think you're missing a $p(1-p)$ under the square root in the denomiinator (which doesn't change the rest of the proof).

Comment: @ClementC. Yes of course, thank you. Now fixed