# Let $B$ be binomial with $(n,p)$ what is the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} P[ B \le c n]$ for $c\in (0,1)$

Tags: probability

This question is follow up to what I asked here.
Let $B$ be binomial with $(n,p)$  what is the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} P[ B \le c n]$ for $c\in (0,1)$.

I think the answer is 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} P[ B \le c n]= \left \{  \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{2} & c=p \\
1 & c>p \\
0 & c<p
 \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

The idea is to use the same proof as is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625866/let-b-have-distribution-textbinomialn-p-then-what-is-lim-n-to-in/3625881#3625881)
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} P[ B \le c n]=  \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left[ \frac{ B -pn}{\sqrt{n}} \le (c-p) \sqrt{n} \right]
\end{align}

Since $\frac{ B -pn}{\sqrt{n}}$ convergece to standard normal we have that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left[ \frac{ B -pn}{\sqrt{n}} \le (c-p) \sqrt{n} \right]=  \lim_{n \to \infty} \Phi( (c-p) \sqrt{n} )
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the cdf standard normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct but you did not divide by the variance correctly.

Comment: What do you mean? What did I miss?

Comment: $\frac {B-np} {\sqrt n}$ does not converge to $\Phi$. $\frac {B-np} {\sqrt {n p(1-p)}}$ does.

Comment: Right. Thanks you.